# Return a class template with value template arguments from function

Tags: c++, templates, function-templates, class-template

Suppose I have a simple template class:

```
template <typename ElementType, ElementType Element>
class ConsecutiveMatcher
{
public:
    bool operator () (ElementType lhs, ElementType rhs)
    {
        return lhs == Element && rhs == Element;
    }
};
```

I would usually make instantiation simpler than `ConsecutiveMatcher<wchar_t, L'\\'>()` by providing a function which can infer the template argument types based on the parameter types:

```
template <typename ElementType>
ConsecutiveMatcher<ElementType, Element /* ?? */> 
    MakeConsMatcher(ElementType Element)
{
    return ConsecutiveMatcher<ElementType, Element>();
}
```

However, in this case, `MakeConsMatcher(L'\\')` will not work, because the function needs to return a class whose template does not only contain a type, but also a value.

How can I return a class template from a function which has not only type template arguments, but also value template arguments?

Comment: Templates are compile-time beasts. If you using various `Element` values on runtime, can you just make `Element` a constructor parameter?

Comment: Static types are ok in my use-case, I'm just looking for a way to omit the `wchar_t` and use automatic type deduction during instantiation. I guess it just isn't possible.

Answer (score 1):

You want a runtime computed value turned into an template argument? it's not possible.

Comment: Would something like this be possible with C++11 `constexpr`?

Comment: the fundamental problem is, that you can not turn a possibly runtime computed value into a new type (if you change a template parameter, you define a new type).

Answer (score 1):

> I'm just looking for a way to omit the wchar_t and use automatic type deduction during instantiation.

I can imagine such situations:

1. **Argument type only known at runtime** (and you have no any idea about it): you cannot handle it with templates: you will want to redesign your code and use inheritance and virtual functions (or, probably, mix both, templates and inheritance)
2. **Argument type known at compile-time, argument value known at runtime**: left *Type* of argument in template argument list and pass argument *value* to constructor, then, for user's convenience, make factory function to deduce type

   ```
   template<typename T>
   struct MyType
   {
       template <class T>
       MyType(const T& defaultValue) :
            value(defaultValue)
       {}
       T value;
   };

   template<typename T>
   MyType<T> MyFactory(const T& defaultValue)
   {
       return MyType<T>(defaultValue);
   }

   int main()
   {
       char c = 'a';
       wchar_t w = L'a';
       int i = 42;
       float f = 3.14f;

       auto mt_char = MyFactory(c);
       auto mt_wchar = MyFactory(w);
       auto mt_int = MyFactory(i);
       auto mt_float = MyFactory(f);
   }
   ```
3. **At compile-time you know a list of Types and want they behave differently** (for example have different default values): make template specializations for each type from a list, then, for user's convenience, create typedefs

   ```
     template<typename T> struct MyType
     {
           MyType(const T& defaultValue) :
       value(defaultValue)
             {}

        T value;
    };

    template<>
    struct MyType <char>
    {
       MyType() :
        value('c')
       {}

       char value;
    };


    template<>
    struct MyType <wchar_t>
    {
       MyType() :
        value(L'w')
       {}

       wchar_t value;
    };

    typedef MyType<char> MyTypeChar;
    typedef MyType<wchar_t> MyTypeWchar;

    int main()
    {
      MyTypeChar mt_char_default;
      MyTypeWchar mt_wchar_default;
    }
   ```

In this case, user still can instantiate own specializations. Example of that approach is a [`std::basic_string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) class.
Further, you can simplify your specializations, if make class members `static` or `static const`  and for integral types just define in member list:

```
template<>
struct MyType <char>
{
    static const char value = 'c';
};
```